# basic numerical integration question related to case of high positive volatility skew

Tags: monte-carlo, distribution, market, implied

is the below equation true irrespective of if that 2nd derivative turns out to be negative or >1 , (ie even if theres an arbitrage) ?

the reason i ask is that i am writing a single asset montecarlo (numerical integration) based on a market implied distribution.
i want to see the affect of changing the vol smile slope on pricing.
i am using linear normal vol smile.  (i know that normal vols are arbitrageable).
when i make slope more than 0.5 (change in vol per 1bp change in strike) , then my convergence to market price is very bad.
What is the mathematical reason for that?  I guess it may be because of probabilities outside 0-100% , but mathematically, i am not sure why thats not allowed, as all we are doing here really is a numeric integration , which is like reverse engineering.
how do i know what limits to do my numerical integration - is it enough to go out to the 99.99% point?

here is the equation i am talking about (copied from word, sorry about formatting) :

$c_k=∫_k^∞(x-k)   (d^2 c_k)/(dx^2 ) dx$

here are some more details of what i have done:
i have done this all in excel.
i could have used some VBA, but apparently, for this task , VBA would be slower than excel, perhaps because VBA is not 'native'.

1. i calc vol, simply at normal vol(K) = given atm vol + given slope * (K-F).
   2, i use bachelier to get price.
2. i do this for small strike increments of 1bp apart for a big range (from delta% 0.01 - 99.99)
3. then i calc 1-sided dV/dK = CDF.
4. then i have a new table of %iles from 0.005 to 99.995 going up by 0.01% , where i lookup the CDF- and get value.
5. in step 5, i initially did with step function interp , then i did linear interp , that did not help at all

Comment: Hi, it would be beneficial if you added your simulation code and/or the corresponding equations. Thanks

Comment: its in excel. i suppose i could share that, but my post is clear enough

Comment: Sorry, I cannot fully understand what you are asking. It would be necessary to know how you come up with the density, how are you calibrating it, what is your simulated product, how are you performing the density inversion/Integration?

Comment: i wrote that there.  i wrote the density is based on a linear normal vol smile.  normal vol is linear in strike.

Comment: 1. i calc vol.  2, i use bachelier to get price.  3. i do this for small strike increments of 1bp apart for a big range (from delta% 0.01 - 99.99)

Comment: then i calc 1-sided dV/dK = CDF.  then i have a new table of %iles from 0.005 to 99.995 going up by 0.01% , where i lookup the CDF- and get value.

Comment: I agree with @Kermittfrog. This question isn’t clear. You can’t expect people to guess or analyze the comments to first understand your problem and then based on their best guess of your problem to come up with a solution.

Comment: well, if i add my above comments to the post, would that be enough?

Comment: Hi Randor, if you'd add your steps in some detail that would be helpful. It would be helpful if you added code (R, python, VBA) or at least the mathematics behind it with some proper formatting. That would be quite helpful to our understanding of your problem!

Comment: sorry Randor, the formula does not help. Where are you applying Monte Carlo? Where are you applying Numerical Integration? How are you originally calculating the option prices? Bachelier's model? Black / Black Scholes Merton? How are you interpolating your implied volatilities? How are you applying the shifts?

Comment: i wrote already most of that!  1. my input is a linear normal vol smile - linear in strike.
2. by montecarlo, i mean numerical integration.  3. original option prices are done with bachelier formula using normal vols i calculated in step 1.  4. i didnt specify my interpolation as i dont think my divergence problem is due to that , 5. what do you mean by shifts?

Comment: A wild guess: If you are playing around with volatility surfaces / curves, do note that there are some no-arbitrage constraints to be adhered to. You cannot *bump* some volatility by too much as $d^2C/dK^2$ must stay positive. Hence, you need $d^2C/dK^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow C_{KK} + 2C_{K\sigma}\sigma_K\sigma_K+C_{\sigma\sigma}\sigma_K^2+C_{\sigma}\sigma_{KK}\geq 0$

Comment: that is my question!! - looking at the math formula , i dont see in the formula that d2C/dK2 must be positive , thats my q - if thats required , where is that clear from the maths?

Comment: Please edit all the details you wrote into a question into the question. It's not efficient for folks to retrace all the steps.

Comment: ok done. @Kermittfrog if you can explain why d2C/dK2 must be positive (i know ofcourse for no arb it must be positive - but who cares about arb here , i simply have a math formula , i dont see in that formula why if its positive or negative matters.  Also i'd be very interested to understand the expansion of it that you wrote there if you can explain that, many thanks!

Comment: If your scenario volatility curve is only a slope (your step 1) then: do you produce negative volatilities somewhere? Also: Why do you expect your new volatilities to recover market prices? You changed them in the first place, no?

Comment: i expect my new volatilities to recover the input volatilities (the linear volsmile).  those input volatilities are defined as implied from market prices.      i floor my vols at 10bp  .

Comment: @Kermittfrog   i hope its clear now?

Comment: Meta comment: Please do edit your question properly; don't add necessary information in the comments :-D.

Comment: If I get you correctly: You get negative implied densities using your method. Where is the negative density observed? At the point where your flooring kicks in? everywhere along the real line? Note: If you observe negative implied densities, it is quite possible that you cannot recover observed prices.

Comment: i dont see a negative density , but i do see the 1st order derivative go above 100% - i see that at the very high strikes.